# Cleanest way to rewrite nested if

Tags: java

I have some code like this:

```
public ClassName func(@Nullable ClassName instance){
  ClassName returnVal = instance;

  if(instance != null){
    V1 v = instance.getV();
    if(someCondition(v)){
      returnVal = null;
    }
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

I am trying to find a way to write this nicely, the nested `if` isn't that great.

Secondly, if `instance` is null, it could be misleading to do `returnVal = instance`, when I mean `returnVal = null`, so thats also something.

Thirdly, if `someCondition(v)` is true then I set `returnVal` to null, so that also isn't ideal, since I set `returnVal = instance` in the first line, which if `null` then is null and I also it again in `returnVal = null`, so its kind of duplication?

What is the cleanest way to rewrite this and why?

Answer (score 4):

Invert the first `if`, and test for `null`. Then you only need a single or to test for *`someCondition`* (and can return `null`). Otherwise, you return the original `instance`. Eliminating temporary variables can lead to more readable code (but should be used when they improve readability). Putting that together here, you could write

```
public ClassName func(@Nullable ClassName instance) {
    if (instance == null || someCondition(instance.getV())) {
        return null;
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Or use ternary operator and no `if` statements at all: `return  (instance == null || someCondition(instance.getV()) ? null : instance);`

Comment: @Andreas No need for the extra parens. `return instance == null || someCondition(instance.getV()) ? null : instance;` would do it.

Comment: or `return instance != null && someCondition(instance.getV()) ? null : instance;`

Comment: Quirk code style of mine : Boolean expressions are always parenthesized, inherited from the fact that `if` and `while` requires parentheses around their boolean expressions, but no parentheses if the boolean expression is part of a bigger construct (`for` loop, and `?:` ternary operator). So I use e.g. `a = b + c`, but `a = (b == c)` and `a = (b == c ? d : e)` and `for (a = 1; b == c; d = e)`. Helps clarify intended distinction between `=` and `==`. I'm just quirky that way. 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java Optional to look *functional*, you can try

```
return Optional.ofNullable(instance)
    .filter(instanceValue -> someCondition(instanceValue.getV()))
    .orElse(null);
```

This is exactly what Elliott Frisch's answer states.